# Font Awesome Icons not displaying in Chrome or IE but are in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, font-awesome

I've spent way too much time trying figure out why on earth my font awesome icons are not showing up in Chrome. This is a django project but that shouldn't matter.. The css files are loading just fine but the elements for the font awesome icons are not displaying in chrome or IE however they are in Firefox. If anyone has any idea what I could be doing wrong... Here are my snippets. My files are in the correct locations so that isn't the issue either.

```
     {% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Naomi's blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></span></a>
                <a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></span></a>
            {% endif %}    
            <h1><a href="/">Naomi's Blog</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Font-awesome.css bit:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

My CSS file:

```
.page-header {
    background-color: #20B2AA;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}

.page-header h1, .page-header h1 a, .page-header h1 a:visited, .page-header h1 a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 36pt;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.date {
    color: #828282;
}

.save {
    float: right;
}

.post-form textarea, .post-form input {
    width: 100%;
}

.top-menu, .top-menu:hover, .top-menu:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    font-size: 26pt;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.post {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.post h1 a, .post h1 a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: What, if anything, do you see in the browser's Dev Tools console (e.g. hit F12) on page load?

Comment: Do they load correctly if you use the CDN (https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/)? If so, that implies a server configuration issue.

Comment: Where are the fonts located on the server because they are relative to where the css file is.

Comment: @EricLaw I do see that on the Networks tab the fontawesome files load. However they do not show up on the elements tab. There are no errors they just do not show up at all.

Comment: @TiesonT. they do not. I have tried referencing them from my a server as well as using a CDN url.. they show up in firefox but not chrome its very odd...

Comment: @Darkrum they are where they should be static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css & static/font-awesome/fonts/font-awesome.css

Comment: And the font files are in /fonts?

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed? That's a known issue that is labeled as "won't fix"

Comment: @Darkrum yes I mistakenly referenced font-awesome.css under the fonts folder in my prior comment but yes the font files are in the fonts folder.

Comment: @TiesonT. unfoturnately no - I checked into that as well and no there are not... this is a bit maddening. I am developing on a linux box but again that shouldn't matter. I checked the site on a my work laptop which has win7 installed and same issue there as well. Not that OS should be the reason for conflict only stating to show I've been trying other browsers because this is making me just nuts.

Comment: Well, Chrome is likely requesting the .woff2 file, and Apache isn't necessarily configured to serve that MIME correctly out of the box.

Comment: @TiesonT. ahh nice thought let me fiddle around with that and see what happens.

Comment: @NaomiSee try using this https://www.cesanta.com/products/binary barebones webserver on windows and try serving a plain html with font-awesome as the only thing in it.

Comment: @NaomiSee any luck? it's been a while but i'm in the same boat -_-

Comment: No color for fontawesome icons either in Chrome